# iPage Connect PHP to my Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to programming. I have a website on iPage. Now, I am learning PHP and one of the things I am learning is to connect PHP to mySql database. I am using the following:
mysql_connect(host name, username, password)

My question is, why I am not getting an error? 
no matter what username and password and even host name i enter, it just accepts it!

This is the code I am trying (the username and password are just as example)

```
<?php
mysql_connect('ipage','admin','password');
echo 'Connected!';
?>
```

when I run it, it just says connected even though my username and password are not admin, password.

Comment: If you are learning, don't learn the `mysql_*` commands. They are becoming deprecated, start with the more modern (and more secure) `mysqli_*` or PDO object.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider MySQLi is just as secure as MySQL if you don't use the bound parameters

Answer (score 2):

Use `mysqli_*`, beacuse `mysql_*` is deprecated and will be removed in the future:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
if(mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
{
    die('Error in connection to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    echo 'Connected successfully';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking if you are connected.
You need to use something like this:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

My suggestion is to start reading some docs, they have some great examples and you can really learn a lot. [DOCUMENTATION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*`